# How to take out everything before dash(-) in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I want to extract a certain part of a row.  if there is something like this ..." abcd - productA", " zas1234 - productC", how do I extract everything before the dash(-)?

I tried a left(column name,'-') it didnt work. I am on SQL Server 2012.

The column  from which I am trying to extract is a varchar column.

It would be great if someone could help me.

Comment: Have you try to google with your exact title? You can find your solution this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
select SUBSTRING(column_name, 1, CHARINDEX('-', column_name)-1) from table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

DECLARE @varStr VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @varStr='abcd - productA'

SELECT CHARINDEX('-',@varStr)

SELECT LEFT(@varStr,CHARINDEX('-',@varStr)-1)